# Differentiate Numbers and Date in MSExcel

Tags: vba, excel, date, excel-formula

I am processing a large set of data. The data contain both numbers, String and Date. I want to differentiate between Date, String and Numbers. I am facing problem in differentiating between Numbers and Date.

I am currently using the below formula.

```
=(IF(TYPE(A1)=2,A1,TEXT(A1,"mmmm d, yyyy"))&"& "&IF(TYPE(B1)=2,B1,TEXT(B1,"mmmm d, yyyy"))&"& "&IF(TYPE(C1)=2,C1,TEXT(C1,"mmmm d, yyyy")))
```

If I give 1, It is formatting it as Date January 01, 1900

Even I tried `ISNUMBER` function, It's returning true for a date as well, e.g: `ISNUMBER(10/01/1900)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ISNUMBER` doesn't work because dates are numbers in actual sense. It's just the formatting that makes them appears as dates. For example `00/01/1900` is 0 formatted as a date. The same applies for `TYPE` function as it will return a `1` for a number (whether the number is formatted as a number or date)

Use this:

```
=LEFT(CELL("format",A1),1)
```

It returns a `d` if `A1` is formatted as date.

Comment: I was just curious because I never used `CELL("format",A1)` but I get a `S` no matter if formatted as date or default.

Comment: @Nitesh Halai: Thank you!!! It worked

=LEFT(CELL("format",A8),1)

 returns "G" If it a Number.

Comment: @peh, that's strange. Is that English Excel? In English Excel, the exponential format returns `S2`, but nothing returns just `S`

Comment: One thing to watch out for - if a cell is formatted as a date it will still show D1 if you change the contents of the cell to a text string.

Comment: @teylyn no it is a German Excel 2016 and `CELL("format",A1)` returns a `S` and the [German Microsoft help](https://support.office.com/de-de/article/ZELLE-Funktion-51bd39a5-f338-4dbe-a33f-955d67c2b2cf) doesn't show `S` only as a possible return value at all, so that's really strange. German help lists the same return values as [English help](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CELL-function-51bd39a5-f338-4dbe-a33f-955d67c2b2cf) but no `S`. Maybe because my OS date format is `YYYY-MM-DD` by default? But still strange that it is `S` then.

Comment: There is a function in Google spreadsheets which can easily predict the date value using the format.

ISDATE(VALUE) will return TRUE if the value is date formatted. Else It will return FALSE.

If someone is using Google spreadsheet they can use this function.